# Como limpio mi Canvas en python despues de haber mostrado una imagen y poder mostrar otra nueva?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hola me gustara saber como puedo limpiar mi canvas después de haber mostrado una imagen , coloque una función de nombre borrar par poder limpiar la imagen que se mostró y poder seleccionar una nueva y esta se muestre en el canvas. Si alguien puede ayudarme se los voy agradecer,dejo mi código.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk    
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import Canvas
from tkinter import NW
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from sys import argv
import tkinter as tk


ventana = tk.Tk ()
ventana.geometry("900x900+0+0")
ventana.title("")
fondo=PhotoImage(file="p1.gif")
lblFondo=Label(ventana,image=fondo).place(x=0,y=0) #fondo 


##########


img_frame = tk.Frame(ventana, height=600, width=800, bg='#faf0e6')
img_frame.pack()
canvas = tk.Canvas (img_frame, height=600, width=800, bg='#faf0e6', relief=tk.SUNKEN)

sbarV = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
sbarH = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
sbarV.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
sbarH.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

canvas.config(yscrollcommand=sbarV.set)
canvas.config(xscrollcommand=sbarH.set)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

###########



# Variable global q
imagenL = None
ruta = "";


def abrir():
    global imagenL
    global ruta


    ventana.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users///")
    ruta=ventana.filename
    imagen = Image.open(ruta)
    imagenL = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
    canvas.create_image(100,100,anchor="center",image=imagenL) 



##AQUI DEFINO UNA FUNCIÓN PARA BORRAR O LIMPIAR MI CANVAS DESPUES DE HABER MOSTRADO UNA IMAGEN

def borrar():
    imagenL.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 


#________MENÚ información de ayuda 
class Ayuda_Dialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        text = ("Bienvenido al menú de ayuda\n\n")

        self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.top.title("Ayuda")
        display = tk.Text(self.top)
        display.pack()
        display.insert(tk.INSERT, text)
        display.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        b = tk.Button(self.top, text="Cerrar", command=self.cerrar)
        b.pack(pady=5)
        b.config(bg="CadetBlue")## bg es el boton de cerrar ,aqui se puede cambiar

    def cerrar(self):
        self.top.destroy()

class Main_Window:
    def __init__(self,  ventana):
        mnuAyuda.add_command(label="Ayuda",command=self.ayuda)
    def ayuda(self):
        Ayuda_Dialog(ventana)


barraMenu=Menu(ventana)
#crear los menús .............................................................. 
mnuArchivo=Menu(barraMenu)
mnuBorrar=Menu(barraMenu)
mnuAyuda=Menu(barraMenu)


#crear los comandos de los menús..........
mnuArchivo.add_command(label="Abrir",command = abrir)
#mnuArchivo.add_command(label="Guardar",command = guardar)
#mnuArchivo.add_command(label="Guardar como",command = guardar)
mnuArchivo.add_separator()
mnuArchivo.add_command(label="Salir",command=ventana.destroy)
mnuBorrar.add_command(label="Limpiar", command = borrar)
```

## ................................................................

```
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Archivo",menu=mnuArchivo)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Ayuda",menu=mnuAyuda)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Limpiar",menu=mnuBorrar)

ventana.config(menu=barraMenu)

if __name__ == "__main__":            
    Main_Window(ventana)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"""
Cambié un poco el código, porque no conseguía hacerlo funcionar en un comienzo.
Lo importante es la línea 55: lienzo.delete("all")
"""
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Canvas, NW, Menu, filedialog, Label, Scrollbar, Frame, Toplevel, Text, Button
from tkinter import SUNKEN, VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL, LEFT, RIGHT, BOTH, BOTTOM, Y, X, INSERT, DISABLED
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from sys import argv

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("300x300+0+0")
ventana.title("")
#fondo=PhotoImage(file="p1.gif")
#lblFondo=Label(ventana,image=fondo).place(x=0,y=0)


##########
img_frame = Frame(ventana, height=200, width=200, bg='#faf0e6')
img_frame.pack()
lienzo = Canvas(img_frame, height=100, width=100, bg='#faf0e6', relief=SUNKEN)

sbarV = Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=lienzo.yview)
sbarH = Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=lienzo.xview)
sbarV.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
sbarH.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

lienzo.config(yscrollcommand=sbarV.set)
lienzo.config(xscrollcommand=sbarH.set)
lienzo.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
###########


# Variable global q
imagenL = None
ruta = "";


def abrir():
    global imagenL
    global ruta
    global lienzo

    ventana.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users///")
    ruta=ventana.filename
    imagen = Image.open(ruta)
    imagenL = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
    lienzo.create_image(100,100,anchor="center",image=imagenL) 


##AQUI DEFINO UNA FUNCIÓN PARA BORRAR O LIMPIAR MI CANVAS DESPUES DE HABER MOSTRADO UNA IMAGEN

def borrar():
    global lienzo
    lienzo.delete("all")


#________MENÚ información de ayuda 
class Ayuda_Dialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        text = ("Bienvenido al menú de ayuda\n\n")

        self.top = Toplevel(parent)
        self.top.title("Ayuda")
        display = Text(self.top)
        display.pack()
        display.insert(INSERT, text)
        display.config(state=DISABLED)
        b = Button(self.top, text="Cerrar", command=self.cerrar)
        b.pack(pady=5)
        b.config(bg="CadetBlue")## bg es el boton de cerrar ,aqui se puede cambiar

    def cerrar(self):
        self.top.destroy()

class Main_Window:
    def __init__(self,  ventana):
        mnuAyuda.add_command(label="Ayuda",command=self.ayuda)
    def ayuda(self):
        Ayuda_Dialog(ventana)


barraMenu=Menu(ventana)
# crear los menús
mnuArchivo=Menu(barraMenu)
mnuBorrar=Menu(barraMenu)
mnuAyuda=Menu(barraMenu)


# crear los comandos de los menús
mnuArchivo.add_command(label="Abrir",command = abrir)
mnuArchivo.add_separator()
mnuArchivo.add_command(label="Salir",command=ventana.destroy)
mnuBorrar.add_command(label="Limpiar", command = borrar)

barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=mnuArchivo)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Borrar", menu=mnuBorrar)

ventana.config(menu=barraMenu)
```